# Multiple NICs in windows

Tags: windows, networking, routing

I want to something about windows networking that is if a windows has multiple NICs-Network Interface Cards then how windows detect that on which interface internet is available.Also how windows take decision that to which interface it will going to route traffic to.?

Thanks

Comment: Using `route` you will be able to see the routes that are setup. It's based on the NIC configuration and what kind of data/configuration it's able to get from a connection.

Answer (score 1):

Windows use a feature called `metric` for assigning a priority to different network interfaces, which is used to construct the default routing tables that are used to communicate with other devices (both in Internet and the local network), that option is located in the advanced settings of the TCP/IP properties:

[image: Interface metric in Advanced TCP/IP settings]

By default Windows assigns automatically a metric to each interface based in its characteristics, the basic idea is that the interface with the (theoretical) best performance get the higher priority (you can read an official explanation of how it works in the MS article [An explanation of the automatic metric feature](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/299540/an-explanation-of-the-automatic-metric-feature-for-ipv4-routes)). You can use the command `route print` for viewing the current routing tables and the metrics assigned to each device/route.

Regarding how windows detects Internet connection see this entry of the SuperUser blog:

[Windows 7 Network Awareness: How Windows knows it has an Internet connection](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/16/windows-7-network-awareness/)

The TL;DR version is that Windows try to connect a Microsoft site in a predefined way and if it can't access it assumes that there is no Internet connection (this explain why sometimes Windows says that there is no Internet connection but you can browse the web).